# Improve fuzzysearch python performance

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

**details about the goal:** I'm learning basic ML and im tasked with finding the best match between some raw city names and some normalized city names.

**Expected result**: The idea is to find items that are similar as according to the Levenshtein distance, and output the best match on the right column of the raw data df.

**What i did:** Originally, I made a nested loop that compares the first row with the 36k thousand rows, output the smallest and its index, and store that in the right most column. I quickly concluded that it's not a best practice because you're not supposed to loop over pandas df, and the complexity of 10000^36k was just way too much. After some search, i found the following code, which is supposed to work properly:

```
rawdata["Best match"]=rawdata["city"].map(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, normadata["city"])[0])
```

Sadly this algo has been running for an hour on my computer so i dont think it does the job still. What would yall recommend to do this quicker ?

Thank you for any time you would spend on this.

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd
import sys

!pip install fuzzywuzzy
!pip install python-Levenshtein
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

def import_data(file):
    return pd.read_csv(file, header=0, dtype=str)

rawdata = import_data("raw_cities.csv")
rawdata['city']=rawdata['city'].map(str)

normadata = import_data("normalized_cities.csv")
normadata['city']=normadata['city'].map(str)

rawdata["Best match"]=rawdata["city"].map(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, normadata["city"])[0])
```

#my tables look as such

```
                           city
0                        cleron
1                     aveillans
2           paray-vieille-poste
3                         issac
4                         rians
9995      neuville les dieppe |
9996     saint andre de vezines
9997  saint-germain-de-lusignan
9998         bergues-sur-sambre
9999     santa-maria-figaniella

[10000 rows x 1 columns]
                        city
0      abergement clemenciat
1        abergement de varey
2          amberieu en bugey
3        amberieux en dombes
4                    ambleon
35352          m'tsangamouji
35353               ouangani
35354               pamandzi
35355                   sada
35356               tsingoni

[35357 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: A slightly pedantic point: Levenshtein distance is not ML; there's no learning involved. Some might consider it to be AI. I won't participate in the argument about what defines "AI", but "ML" surely requires learning a model from data.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting 10000^36000 for runtime complexity. Levenshtein distance is computed over a pair of strings. There are 36000 strings, so there are < 36000^2 pairs (technically there are "36000 choose 2" = 36000 * 35999 / 2 pairs). There might be some weird trickery you can do to reduce redundant computations (e.g., if two strings are highly similar, then they'll both have similar distances to any given string); maybe there are some research papers on this. But the simplest solution is to compute all pairs' distances. If the df is the issue, convert it to something else first.